# Get owner instance of attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get the instance handle of an attribute when this attribute is passed to a function without its instance. To make it more clear see the example code below:

```
class aClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.anInstanceAttribute = 'ok'

def aFunction(anInstanceAttribute):
    print(anInstanceAttribute)
    #how to get the instance handle ('the self') of the anInstanceAttribute?

a = aClass()
aFunction(a.anInstanceAttribute)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible without introspection/frame hacks.

```
aFunction(a.anInstanceAttribute)
```

The function arguments are fully evaluated before calling the function.  So, the function receives the string object `"ok"` and knows nothing about the instance `a`.  If you want the function to know something about the instance, then pass in `a` instead.

Comment: And those frame inspection approaches are fragile as hell, so putting them into your program is going to cause many more problems than it solves. It's far better to just pass in `a`.